# Select all in check box

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Here is my code:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
$(function () {
 $("#selectall").click(function () {
  $('.name').attr('checked', this.checked);
 });

    $(".name").click(function () {
     if ($(".name").length == $(".name:checked").length) {
       $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
     } else {
       $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
     }
     });
     });
</SCRIPT>
```

and for the form:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></td>
<td>No.</td>
<td class="web" width="400" align="center">Name</td>
<td class="web" width="240" align="center">Username</td>
```

My problem is, when i click the selectall checkbox , it doesnt check all the checkboxes.

Comment: how is this a php question?

Comment: whatjquery will i use?

Comment: @LeRandomGirl Post the full html code, beacuse we could not find any element with `name` as class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/3s7KC/

```
$("#selectall").click(function () {
 $('.name').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

$(".name").click(function () {
 if ($(".name").length == $(".name:checked").length) {
   $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
 } else {
   $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
 }
});

<input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/> Select All
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="1" class="name"/></td>
    <td>No.</td>
    <td class="web" width="100" align="center">Name</td>
    <td class="web" width="140" align="center">Username</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="2" class="name"/></td>
    <td>No.</td>
    <td class="web" width="100" align="center">Name</td>
    <td class="web" width="140" align="center">Username</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have added some extra html code for testing pouposes.